# Adding values from a control into hyperlinkfield querystring

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:HyperLinkField 
                        DataTextField="USERNAME" HeaderText="USERNAME" 
                        NavigateUrl="~/openOrdersDetails.aspx?lookup_id=" SortExpression="USERNAME" 
                        Target="_blank" />
```

How can I write the code above so the NavigateUrl contains a value grabbed from a control on the page?

Eg,

```
NavigateUrl="~/openOrdersDetails.aspx?lookup_id=ValueFromControl"
```

Comment: i dnt think this can be done server side but you can try to achieve this by using jquery

Comment: Depending on the control you target and its location in the page and the type of templated control containing the HyperLink field, you _might_ be able to do it with <%# , or on databinding handler (codebehind side)